Subsetting feature layer on AGOL by querying
Is it possible to subset a huge feature layer (has more than 10000 records) on ArcGIS Online by querying?
I would like to query the records for the year 2024 for example and then export this as file gdb. This way I could backup my feature layer.

I believe the standard way of filtering a layer is to created a Hosted Feature Layer View, so in your case just show data that was in 2024. If that translates to being able to export just that subset, you need to explore.

Thanks for your reply. The feature layer has so many records so I would like query it and then save the resulting part as file gdb using a python code.

You have tagged your question AGOL but you want to subset into a file geodatabase. File geodatabases don't exist in AGOL as a storage format. So if you want to export a subset based upon an attribute query you need to do that in ArcPro. But that depends on the author of the data allowing exporting.

Use the API to query out the requested features, then use either arcpy or geopandas to convert those features into a FGDB and store locally. Take a look into these topics and give it a try on your own. When you run into a speed bump that you can't solve with research, post back with some code where you got stuck.
